# Вызов КриптоПро утилиты csptestf в php для подписи файла в Linux

Tags: php, bash, криптография

Подписываю файл в терминале с помощью команды

```
csptestf -sfsign -sign -detached -add -in in.txt -out out.sgn 
-base64 -my 'certificate_name' -password some_password -alg GOST94_256
```

В результате получаю открепленную подпись.
При вызове команды в php скрипте с помощью метода `shell_exec()` возникает ошибка при получении сертификата, т.к. локальные сертификаты недоступны для пользователя `www-data`.

> An error occurred in running the program.
>   /dailybuildsbranches/CSP_4_0/CSPbuild/CSP/samples/csptest/tmain.c:1616:CertOpenStore
>   Error number 0x2 (2).
>   The system cannot find the file specified.
>   An error occurred in running the program.
>   /dailybuildsbranches/CSP_4_0/CSPbuild/CSP/samples/csptest/signtsf.c:389:Cannot find User certificate: certificate_name
>   Error number 0x2 (2).
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Есть возможность подписать файл в php скрипте сертификатом другого пользователя или сделать сертификат доступным для всех пользователей?
Сертификат установлен в личное хранилище локального пользователя uMy.

Добавлять права в `/etc/sudoers` на выполнение команды `csptestf` под `sudo` для пользователя `www-data` нельзя.
Проверял подписывания файла в bash скрипте, в котором выполняется смена пользователя и подпись файла. При вызове bash скрипта в php возникает ошибка.

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>   sh: echo: I/O error

При установке сертификата в хранилище mCA, mMy также возникает ошибка при подписывании файла в php скрипте.

Comment: А нельзя сертификат выгрузить в файл и дать права www-data на чтение этого файла

Comment: Подпись выполняется закрытым ключом. Сертификат должен быть привязан к этому ключу. Подписать файл с использованием сертификата в файле не получится. Уже проверял. Команда csptestf не воспринимает ссылку на файл сертификата.

Comment: я подписываю обычным openssl, включив поддержку GOST (google по запросу "openssl гост" дает подробные инструкции и там в общем то все просто). не знаю те ли виды подписей вы используете

Comment: Да, openssl позволяет использовать файл сертификата. Но требуется использовать КриптоПро, поэтому спросил как можно подписать файл в php скрипте средствами КриптоПро.

Comment: Так вот вопрос как раз в том, зачем использовать именно крипто-про. у меня тоже ГОСТ сертификат и надо подписывать запросы в госорганы с помощью криптопро, только я включил ГОСТ в openssl и спокойно подписываю им ...

Comment: Это требование задачи. Желательно решить задачу средствами КриптоПро, без настройки ГОСТ в openssl.